# Hide div if the ul is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my `html`,

```
<div id="personaldetails">

    <ul>
        <li class="clear"></li> 
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="clear"></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to hide `div` `personaldetails` when all the ul inside in div is empty.

If the `ul` is having element `<li class="clear"></li>` then the `ul` is considered as to be empty.

How to do this using Jquery ?

Comment: @chris97ong You mean using only CSS, i don't see how you'll do it here?!

Comment: If your list is empty then your div should have height 0. Just remove the default style for `<ul>`

Comment: If your `ul` has 2 `li`: one is with class `clear` and the other contain something then how?

Comment: @Felix If `ul` has 2 `li` with with `class` `clea`r and other contain something different then the `ul` is not considered to be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('#personaldetails').find('ul').each(function(){
   var txt = $("li", this).text();
   if(txt.length <= 0){
      $(this).hide();
   }
});
if(!$('#personaldetails').find('ul:visible').length){
    $('#personaldetails').hide();
}
```

### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vuz6x/1/)

---

And to me you should hide all `ul`, if no ul are visible then you can hide the `#personaldetails` div.

Comment: As `personaldetails` is an id , no need to use `$(this).closest` but only `$('#personaldetails').hide();`

Comment: yeah @fabienpapet i was updating my answer, you can see now.

Answer (score 2):

Even one of answer is already accepted, I think it can be simple as:

```
if($.trim($("#personaldetails").text()) == '') {
    $("#personaldetails").hide();
}
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at that code:

```
function foo(){
    var all_li_clear = true;
    $("#personaldetails > ul > li").each(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass("clear")){
            all_li_clear = false;
            break; // No need to continue now
        }
    });

    if(all_li_clear){
        $("#personaldetails").hide();
    }
}
```

You can see a fiddle example [there](http://jsfiddle.net/Tpwjj/), just comment and discomment `foo();` line.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript solution:

This will only hide the div if all li have clear class

```
        $(function() {
         emptyLi = $('#personaldetails ul li').filter(function(){

            /*if($(this).hasClass('clear')){
             return true;
            }else{
             return false;
            }*/
            return $(this).hasClass('clear');

         }).length;

         if($('#personaldetails ul li').length == emptyLi){

           $('#personaldetails').css('display','none');
         }
        });
```

CSS:

This will hide the li with class clear, so if you not fixed height of ul or li and don't have padding , margin given to ul,li your div personaldetails will get hidden automatically when all li element have class clear

```
        #personaldetails ul li.clear{
          display:none;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

-**UPDATED**-

You can use following code if you are deciding empty class based on **clear** class.

```
if($("#personaldetails ul li:not(.clear)").length == 0) {
    $("#personaldetails").hide();
}
```

Or if you are looking for the ***empty div*** then you can just use the shortest code given by *@Samiul Amin Shanto*  [Like](http://jsfiddle.net/wmqcd/79/):

```
if($.trim($("#personaldetails").text()) == '') {
    $("#personaldetails").hide();
}
```

### **Explanations**

*Method1*:

`$("#personaldetails ul li:not(.clear)")`
This code find all **li** without the **clear** class. Then if no such **li** found, just hide the **div**. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wmqcd/78/)

*Method2*:

`$("#personaldetails").text()` this code return innerHTML text striping all html tags. So no meter what the div contain ul, li or anything else, this will return the plain text content of the div, then striping any white space we can determine if the div is empty. If your intention is to hide the empty div not hiding the div which contain empty ***Ul*** this should be your choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function($) {
    $cnt = 0;
    $('.personalDetails ul li').each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('clear')) $cnt++;
    });
    if($('.personalDetails ul li').length == $cnt) $('.personalDetails').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This asumes that if you have the same amount of li's with the class clear, as there are ul's, they're all empty

```
var $wrapper = $('#personaldetails');
if(  $wrapper.find('ul').length=== $wrapper.find('li.clear').length){ 
    $wrapper .hide(); 
}
```

Everybody's [fiddling examples :)](http://jsfiddle.net/3v7vj/)

Answer (score -2):

```
$("ul li:empty").closest('div#personaldetails').hide();
```

[Sample Code](http://jsfiddle.net/wmqcd/76/)

Comment: @Satpal I don't see in question any referance to any class `empty`

Comment: This will remove the div if 1 empty li is found, even if there are others which are filled. Also, ALWAYS use an id selector with ID only (so no `div` in front of it).

Answer (score -3):

```
#personaldetails ul li.clear{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: This will have just that li, not `#personaldetails`